# Multiple Websites from One Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

I have a number of franchisee websites, and I want them all to pull data from a single database, so that if ever a change is made then I can do this by just editing the table data, as opposed to editing and uploading each website separately (would take ages!)

Works fine on localhost using WAMP (Apache 2.2.22, php 5.3.13 and MySQL 5.5.24) - all sites displaying required information correctly.

Problem is, when I create a new site in live environment after importing the database and uploading the site files I'm presented with a blank page. No error messages.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=####dbname", '####username', '####password');
```

The sites are all hosted on the same VPS (Parallels Plesk 11.5.30)

Any clues anybody?

Cheers!

Comment: enable error reporting and check http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Firstly: chuck on `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: That's great thanks - this gave me the error **Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/sitename.co.uk/httpdocs/getinfo.php on line 13**, which is where info is being fetched from a particular table. When removed, the pages all seem to work with the exception of the page that relies on that particular table (just some undefined variables). Confusing thing is, line 13 looks no different to me than the other lines that do the same job for other pages... Mystery deepens!

Comment: SOLVED - When I imported the DB to live server, the camel-case table name for that table was changed to lower case. Switched the PDO query to lowercase and it works. Is camel case not recommended for table names and suchlike?